# Django -- Pass a dictionary to template and plot a line chart

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I have a dictionary generated in views.py, it looks like this, but has n number of enterprises

```
{ enterprise1: {'Year': ['2014/2015', '2016/2017', '2013/2014'], 
                'no_per_year': [16, 8, 6]}, 
  enterprise2: {'Year': ['2016/2017', '2013/2014', '2014/2015'], 
                'no_per_year': [2, 16, 11]},
  enterprise3: {'Year': ['2016/2017', '2013/2014', '2015/2016'], 
                'no_per_year': [19, 7, 14]},
    ....
    ....
    .... 
}
```

How to pass this dictionary to a template, and plot a line graph which depicts each enterprise and the number of students they recruited in each year.
Json, javascripts are something very new for me, would appreciate any help.
Below is the code, i tried with static data by implicitly writing the data without any loops. How do i transform it to take this data of n enterprises and plot?

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %} 

<script>
{% block jquery %}
$.ajax({
    success: function(data) {
       setchart()
       setchart2()

    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
})
prgcolorset = [
    'rgba(73,170,30,0.4)',
    'rgba(50, 106, 21,0.4)',
    'rgba(219, 58, 29,0.4)',
    'rgba(150, 58, 29, 0.4)',
    'rgba(60, 206, 209, 0.4)',
    'rgba(60, 157, 209, 0.4)',
    'rgba(60, 90, 209, 0.4)',
    'rgba(280, 243, 36, 0.4)',
    'rgba(230, 243, 36, 0.4)',
]
prgcolorborderset =[
    'rgba(73,170,30,1)',
    'rgba(50, 106, 21,1)',
    'rgba(219, 58, 29, 1)',
    'rgba(150, 58, 29, 1)',
    'rgba(60, 206, 209, 1)',
    'rgba(60, 157, 209, 1)',
    'rgba(60, 90, 209, 1)',
    'rgba(280, 243, 36, 1)',
    'rgba(230,243, 36, 1)',

]
function setchart() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    ctx.shadowBlur=20;
    ctx.shadowColor="black";
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels:{{ enterpYear }} ,
                datasets: [
                  {
                    label: '{{ check|safe }}',
                    data: {{ enterpQTD1 }},
                    //backgroundColor: prgcolorset ,
                    borderColor: prgcolorborderset,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    fill: false
                  },
                  {
                    label: 'Ent2',
                    data: {{ enterpQTD2 }},
                    //backgroundColor: prgcolorset ,
                    borderColor:'#26c6da',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    fill: false,
                    borderDash: [10,5]
                  },
                  {
                    label: 'Ent3',
                    data: {{ enterpQTD3 }},
                    //backgroundColor: prgcolorset ,
                    borderColor:'#5c6bc0',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    fill: false,
                    //borderDash: [10,5]
                  }
                ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        },
        title: {
            display: false,
            text: 'Students per year'
        },

        legend: {
            display: true,
            position:'bottom',
        },
        tooltips: {
            mode: 'x'
        }
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first let's start with the plotting.
I recommend using "https://plot.ly/javascript/", this is a very simple JS library, and they have plenty of examples.
about passing the dictionary into a view:
go to views.py, there you either set the model attribute of the view to a the model which holds the data (if there is such model), like so:

```
class SomePage(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'PagesTemplate'
    model = models.TheModelName
```

then, in your template, just use the Django tags '{% object_list %}'
that will hold the dictionary data, always recommended to iterate over it like this:

```
{% for singleObject in object_list %}
            {% if not forloop.first %},{% endif %} # this is how you access your loops meta data (such as counters go to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/ for more information #
            {
               someattribute: "{{ singleObject.someattribute }}",
               .
               .
               .
            }
        {% endfor %}
```

second option, if your data is not stored using a model:
use the 'extra_content' view built-in attribute and insert the dictionary there, just like this:

```
    class SomePage(sometypeofview):
          extra_context = {'your_extra_data': your_extra_data}
```

then, access it in the template itself like this:

```
<h1>{{ your_extra_data}} </h1>
```

here h1 is just an example, put it in whatever tag you want.